# Removing from firebase with VueJS

Tags: firebase, vue.js, firebase-realtime-database, vuejs2

Consider this sample data structure:

```
{
   "blogs": {
      "blog1": {
         "title": "Title 1",
         "text": "Blah blah blah"
         "image": "domain.com/image1"
      },
      "blog2": {
         "title": "Title 1",
         "text": "Blah blah blah"
         "image": "domain.com/image1"
      },
      "blog3": {
         "title": "Title 1",
         "text": "Blah blah blah"
         "image": "domain.com/image1"
      }
   }
}
```

I am mapping these to a list and each one has a delete icon. When I click the icon I fire a function (see below). My problem is, I am having a hard time pointing to the right node. This is a firebase real time database.

```
let blogRef = firebaseDb.ref("blogs");
```

and in my export default

```
removeBlog: function(blog) {
  console.log(blog);
  blogRef.child(blog).remove();

  //this didn't work either
  blogRef.child(blog[".key"]).remove();
},
```

That console.log there returns the node. But it's not removing it. How can I remove the item getting clicked?

Thanks

Comment: Can you try this ref `blogRef = firebaseDb.ref('blogs/blog1');` just to see what happens? That should work.

Comment: Let me check. I see where you're going with it

Comment: @thechaoticpanda Error: Reference.child failed: First argument was an invalid path = "[object Object]". Paths must be non-empty strings and can't contain ".", "#", "$", "[", or "]"

Comment: can you check this url? `https://medium.com/@hasangi/writing-deleting-and-updating-data-in-firebase-realtime-database-with-javascript-f26113ec8c93` the example is pretty clear, the problem is, you are referencing the object itself instead of the pointer to it.

Comment: @thechaoticpanda Yeah I've seen this before but it didn't help me much. In that example there is a userId variable which it holds the value of currentUser.uid most likely. I don't have currentUser. This is not a list of users. I was wondering if there is a way to target the child of the ref.

Comment: can you try this `blogRef.child(blog.key).remove();` that will probably do the trick.

Comment: Didnt work same error as above

Comment: Well, i don't know what else to do

Comment: Can you show the result of `console.log(blog);`?